# Python Pandas grouby

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Im new to python and I'm having trouble grouping a column from a CSV file. I'm trying to find the total price per category.

**CSV:**

```
category,item,quantity,individual_price

shirts,Blue Shirt,3,25.75

shirts,Red Shirt,1,32.09

pants,Jeans,4,87.00

pants,Slacks,2,92.99
```

**This is what I have so far:**

```
import csv
import operator

with open('shopping_cart.csv', 'r') as f:

    sample = open('shopping_cart.csv','r')

    sample.next()

    csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=',')

    sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(3))

for eachline in sort:

    print eachline[3]
```

**Outputs:**

```
25.75

32.09

87.00

92.99
```

Comment: If you are working with tabular data, you can check out pandas dataframes. It comes with lots of built in functions for dealing with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the job.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


d = defaultdict(float)

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        d[line['category']] += float(line['individual_price'])

for category, total_price in d.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(category, total_price))
```

outputs

```
shirts: 57.84
pants: 179.99
```

It uses [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) so we do not have to skip the headers and [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) which allows us to not to initialize every key in the dictionary before assigning to it. It is very useful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's worth answering this of how it would be done in Pandas as well, since it's 3 lines including the import statement.**

```
import pandas as pd

#read in the CSV and reset the index
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('shopping_cart.csv').reset_index()

print(df.groupby('category').agg({'individual_price': sum}))
```

outputs

```
          individual_price
category
pants               179.99
shirts               57.84
```

**If you want to iterate through the prices and do something in that loop:**

```
catagg = df.groupby('category').agg({'individual_price': sum})
for idx, col in catagg.iterrows():
    print(col.name , col.get_value('individual_price'))
```

outputs

```
pants 179.99
shirts 57.84
```

Comment: Great! I appreciate it tandy!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same job with the following code (**data.py**).

In this case, I have just read the CSV file **data.csv** and started processing from the second line (as the first line denotes the name of data fields).

**data.csv**

```
category,item,quantity,individual_price
shirts,Blue Shirt,3,25.75
shirts,Red Shirt,1,32.09
pants,Jeans,4,87.00
pants,Slacks,2,92.99
```

**data.py**

```
data = {}  # mapping data structure: category => total price of all products of that category

with open("data.csv") as csv: 
    for line in csv.readlines()[1:]:
        data_list = line.strip().split(",")

        if data_list[0] not in data:
            data[data_list[0]] = float(data_list[3])
        else:
            data[data_list[0]] = data[data_list[0]] + float(data_list[3])

print(data)

for category in data:
    print(category, " : ", data[category])
```

Thanks.